# How to disabled prettier import css

Tags: javascript, css, import, prettier

This is my order of css imports that should be

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import '../public/assets/css/site.css';
import '../public/assets/css/responsive.css';
import '../public/assets/css/icons.css';
```

But prettier makes it this way for me.

```js
import '../public/assets/css/icons.css';
import '../public/assets/css/responsive.css';
import '../public/assets/css/site.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';
```

Responsive is not working because my responsive.css file is before site.css.

.prettierrc

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 120,
}
```

How can i only disable prettier for these imports